# Vuefity Data Table with select-all event

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I create one data table with option select-all, in each row in my table I add one event in checkbox

```
<v-checkbox
        primary
        hide-details
        v-model="props.selected"
        @change="selecionarPedido"
      ></v-checkbox>
```

So It`s possible to put a event in seletAll checkbox (that checkbox in the header? or an envent in v-checkbox that fire when the select-all change the value?

Comment: in sample don`t have anything about events, the view I aready done

Comment: would watching the array of selected values works for you ? If not, I think you will have to edit Vuetify code to add the event listener